# Blender 2.9 particle not rendering in final

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I was doing the donut tutorial and the sprinkles were rendering in the viewport but not the final. Any idea why?

Edit:
This is my blend file. [File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nDoVhvEZrIbIA2oL166Xr2F6Quiq738l/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: have you enabled the camera icon of the particle system?

Comment: Would the particle system mean the object with the particles on it. If so, yes.

Comment: No, the particle system itself has those visibilty icons as well.

Comment: Found it. Thanks!